# анимация появления меню на айфоне

Tags: ios, css-animation

Всем привет. 
Есть [сайт](http://funny.sem-dev.co.ua), и [проблема](https://api.asm.skype.com/v1/objects/0-eus-d9-4b2ddde2fef662857a00370376cfb618/views/video) которая появляется на айфонах. 
Код стилей меню представлен ниже. 
Как можно такое пофиксить?

```
&__menu
        position: absolute
        left: 0
        top: 0
        opacity: 0
        transform: translateX(-100%)
        width: 100%
        min-height: 100vh
        max-width: 657px
        background: #fff
        z-index: 5
        padding:
            top: 134px
            left: 14px
        transition: transform .3s cubic-bezier(.45,.05,.55,.95)
        &.active
            transform: translateX(-10px)
            opacity: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в `transform: translateX(-10px)`
А точнее в отрицательном значении